# Regarding IndexOutOfRange error asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

Hi
i am creating online quiz. For that i am creating arrays of answers selected by user. i used following code for that, it gives correct array but sometimes gives error "Index was outside the range"

```
    //rsel is session values for selected answer
            int rsel = Convert.ToInt32(Session["rblsel"]);
// [Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"] indicates size of array of no. of questions
            int[] ansarray = new int[Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) - 1];

            int[] temp = (int[])Session["arrofans"];
            int j,n;

                if (temp == null)
                    n = 0;
                else
                    n = temp.Length;
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                ansarray[j] = temp[j];
                }
                ansarray[j] = rsel;
                Session["arrofans"] = ansarray;
```

Help me to find out exact error. Asp.net,c#
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you reducing the "counter" by one?

```
int[] ansarray = new int[Convert.ToInt32(Session["Counter"]) - 1];
```

It looks like that should probably be a `+ 1`... but to be honest it would be simpler to use the size of `ansarray` - and use `Array.Resize` to effectively extend it:

```
int[] ansarray = (int[])Session["arrofans"];
Array.Resize(ref ansarray, ansarray.Length + 1);
ansarray[ansarray.Length - 1] = rsel;
Session["arrofans"] = ansarray;
```

That way you don't even need the "Counter" part of the session.

Comment: @user701590: Then change it so that it does work. If that isn't enough detail for you, please consider giving *us* more detail about the way in which it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

One possible **OutOfRange** could be triggered when

```
 **arrofans.length >= Counter**
```

Answer (score 0):

temp.Length should not be bigger than ansarray.Length, or precisely from your code it ansarray.Length must be temp.Length+1 or bigger. To avoid your problem you must change it to for (j = 0; j < n && j < (ansarray.Length-1); j++) but i don't know if it will suite your case